# Can't find correct constant in limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the values of $a$ and $b$  for the series

$$a_n=\frac{(1-a)n^2+2n+b}{an^2+n+1}$$

With the following conditions:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=2$    and    $a_1=0$

I get the value of $a$ just fine, but I just can't get the correct value for $b$. In the solutions, $b=-\frac{8}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0=a_1=\frac{(1-a)+2+b}{a+2}\implies a-b=3\;\;\;(**)$$

and using arithmetic of limits and the fact that the right hand expression for $\;a_n\;$  is a rational function in $\;n\;$:

$$2=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{1-a}a\implies a=\frac13$$

and substituting in (**):

$$\frac13-b=3\implies b=-\frac83$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot, wasn't using my brain. I interpreted $a_1=0$ as $a=0$ in the series instance $a_1$. Total brainfart.